# How to improve computation time for this following code

Tags: matlab

can you give me suggestion to my code to improve time computation. because this code will take so much time. and some time i will not get the result. my case is how to combine RandomMatriceA [1 12] and RandomMatriceB [0 2].

Example:

```
ProcessTime=[2 2 2 3 3] %number of consecutive value RandomMatriceA

RandomMatriceA=[1 2 3 4 5;
               3 4 2 1 5;
               1 4 2 3 5;
               5 1 2 3 4]

RandomMatriceB=[0 2 0 0 1;%humber of consecutive zeros
                0 0 0 1 1;
                1 2 1 0 0;
                0 0 1 1 1]

Result   =[1 1 0 0 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 0 5 0 0 0;
           3 3 4 4 4 2 2 0 1 1 0 5 5 5 0 0;
           0 1 1 0 0 4 4 4 0 2 2 3 3 5 5 5;   
           5 5 5 1 1 0 2 2 0 3 3 0 4 4 4 0]

NewMatric{1}=[1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
              0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0;
              0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
              0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;

NewMatric{2}= just only identify value 2;
NewMatric{3}= for value 3  
NewMatric{4}= value 4;
```

And actually, i make this following code to force every column in NewMatric must have sum of value 1 per column is equal to 2.

If one of you want to give me suggestion to improve computation time, thanks you so much.

```
    clc
clear all
A=2;
B=12;
C=4;
ProcessTime= [ 11 11 11 11 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 ]; %Converting Matrice

RandomMatriceA=zeros(A,B,C);
RandomMatriceB=zeros(A,B,C);
SumRandomMatriceB=zeros(1,A,C);
ConvertMatriceA=zeros(A,B,C);
ProcessRandomMatriceA=zeros(A,B,C);
StartProcess=zeros(A,B,C);
ZerosCoordinate=zeros(A,B,C);
total=zeros(1,1,C);

%make first random matrice
for ii=1:C;    
    for a=1:A
        RandomMatriceA(a,:,ii)=randperm(B); %batasan tidak boleh satu kelompok melakukan lebih dari satu aktivitas dalam satu waktu
    end
end
%make second random matrice
for ii=1:C;
    RandomMatriceB(:,:,ii)=randint(A,B,[0 2]);
end

%Make sure sum all element per row in RandomMatriceB <=11
for ii=1:C;
    SumRandomMatriceB(1,:,ii)=sum(RandomMatriceB(:,:,ii),2); 
    for jj=1:A,
        while SumRandomMatriceB(1,jj,ii) > 11 
              RandomMatriceB(jj,:,ii)=randint(1,B,[0 2]);
              SumRandomMatriceB(1,:,ii)=sum(RandomMatriceB(:,:,ii),2);
        end
    end  
end

%After making RandomMatriceA and RandomMatriceB, then Make New Matrice
%which has size (8,85,10)
%To know varible of new matrice which is result of combining
%RandomMatriceA,RandomMatriceB and ProcessTime
for ii=1:C;
    for a=1:A,
        for b=1:B,
            ConvertMatriceA(a,b,ii)=ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(a,b,ii));%FirstVarible:Consecutive The Number of value in all element of RandomMatriceA
            ProcessRandomMatriceA(a,b,ii)=ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(a,b,ii))+RandomMatriceB(a,b,ii);
            EndProcess=cumsum(ProcessRandomMatriceA,2);%secondVaribale:to know in which column The Consecutive value RandomMatrice will be end
            StartProcess(a,b,ii)=EndProcess(a,b,ii)-(ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(a,b,ii))-1);%ThirdVariable:to know in which column The Consecutive Value will be start
        end
    end
end

%To know in which column and row in new matrice will have zeros
 for ii=1:C,        
    for a=1:A;
        for b=1:B
            if RandomMatriceB (a,b,ii)~=0
               ZerosCoordinate(a,b,ii)=StartProcess(a,b,ii)-RandomMatriceB(a,b,ii);%To know in which column in new matrice will have value zeros
            else
               ZerosCoordinate(a,b,ii)=RandomMatriceB(a,b,ii);
            end
        end
    end
 end
%to force/make column 43th will be filled by zeros in every row.
for ii=1:C;
       while size(find(ZerosCoordinate(:,:,ii)==43),1)<A, %looping untuk mendapatkan hari libur diminggu ke 43
           for a=1:A;
              if numel(find(ZerosCoordinate(a,:,ii)==43))==1, %mengharuskan adanya libur di minggu ke 43
                 continue;
              else
                 %make sure sum of element new random row in RandomMatriceB
                 %<=11
                 newRow = randi([0 2],1,B);
                 sumnewRow=sum(newRow,2);
                 while sumnewRow >11,
                       newRow = randi([0 2],1,B);
                       sumnewRow=sum(newRow,2);
                 end
                 %replace newRow to row in RandomMatriceB
                 RandomMatriceB(a,:,ii)=newRow; %proses pergantian baris yang tidak sesuai dengan konstrain
                 %random row in RandomMatriceA
                 RandomMatriceA(a,:,ii)=randperm(B); %randoming baris kromosom yang tidak sesuai dengan konstrain
                 %Try to know variabel to make NewMatrice
                 for b=1:B;
                     ConvertMatriceA(a,b,ii)=ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(a,b,ii));
                     ProcessRandomMatriceA(a,b,ii)=ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(a,b,ii))+RandomMatriceB(a,b,ii);
                     EndProcess=cumsum(ProcessRandomMatriceA,2);
                     StartProcess(a,b,ii)=EndProcess(a,b,ii)-(ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(a,b,ii))-1);
                 end
                 for b=1:B
                     %To know column and row which has value zeros
                    if RandomMatriceB(a,b,ii)~=0
                       ZerosCoordinate(a,b,ii)=StartProcess(a,b,ii)-RandomMatriceB(a,b,ii);
                    else
                       ZerosCoordinate(a,b,ii)=RandomMatriceB(a,b,ii); 
                    end
                end
             end
           end
       end
end

%Make New Matrice (8,85,10) by considering variable above 
max_row_length = max(StartProcess(:,B) + ConvertMatriceA(:, B) - 1); %to know row length
result = zeros(size(StartProcess, 1),max_row_length, size(StartProcess,3)); %preallocation size

for row = 1 : size(StartProcess, 1)
    for column = 1 : size(StartProcess, 2)
         for depth = 1 : size(StartProcess,3)
             s = StartProcess(row, column,depth);
             c = ConvertMatriceA(row, column,depth);
             v = RandomMatriceA(row,column,depth);
             result(row, s : s + c - 1,depth) = v;%this matrix is new matrix (8,85,10) which is result of combining RandomMatriceA,RandomMatriceB and ProcessTime
         end
     end
end

%Make A new Matrice per Value (B).
newMatrice = arrayfun(@(b) (result == b).*cumsum((result == b),2),nonzeros(unique(result)), 'UniformOutput', false);  %indikator pemakaian bagian

%to know how many number of value 1 per column in matrice
%bagian1,bagian2,bagian3 and bagian4
SumOnePerColumn=cell(1,4);
SumOnePerColumn{1}=sum(newMatrice{1}==1);
SumOnePerColumn{2}=sum(newMatrice{2}==1);
SumOnePerColumn{3}=sum(newMatrice{3}==1);
SumOnePerColumn{4}=sum(newMatrice{4}==1);

%to count how many column which has sum of value one per column ~=2&~=0,
gab=cell(1,4);
gabb{1}=sum(SumOnePerColumn{1}~=0 &SumOnePerColumn{1}~=2);
gabb{2}=sum(SumOnePerColumn{2}~=0 &SumOnePerColumn{2}~=2);
gabb{3}=sum(SumOnePerColumn{3}~=0 &SumOnePerColumn{3}~=2);
gabb{4}=sum(SumOnePerColumn{4}~=0 &SumOnePerColumn{4}~=2);


for yyy=1:C; 
total(1,1,yyy)= gabb{1}(1,1,yyy)+gabb{2}(1,1,yyy)+gabb{3}(1,1,yyy)+gabb{4}(1,1,yyy);%Total
end

for ii=1:C;
    if total(:,:,ii)==0;
        continue;
    else
       while total(:,:,ii)~=0;%to make total=0 by randoming RandomMatriceA and RandomMatriceB
             for a=1:A
                 RandomMatriceA(a,:,ii)=randperm(B); %batasan tidak boleh satu kelompok melakukan lebih dari satu aktivitas dalam satu waktu
             end
             %make second random matrice
             RandomMatriceB(:,:,ii)=randint(A,B,[0 2]);
             %Make sure sum all element per row in RandomMatriceB <=11
             SumRandomMatriceB(:,:,ii)=sum(RandomMatriceB(:,:,ii),2); 
             for jj=1:A,
                    while SumRandomMatriceB(1,jj,ii) > 11 
                    RandomMatriceB(jj,:,ii)=randint(1,B,[0 2]);
                    SumRandomMatriceB(1,:,ii)=sum(RandomMatriceB(:,:,ii),2);
                    end
             end  
             for a=1:A,
                 for b=1:B,
                      ConvertMatriceA(a,b,ii)=ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(a,b,ii));%FirstVarible:Consecutive The Number of value in all element of RandomMatriceA
                      ProcessRandomMatriceA(a,b,ii)=ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(a,b,ii))+RandomMatriceB(a,b,ii);
                      EndProcess=cumsum(ProcessRandomMatriceA,2);%secondVaribale:to know in which column The Consecutive value RandomMatrice will be end
                      StartProcess(a,b,ii)=EndProcess(a,b,ii)-(ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(a,b,ii))-1);%ThirdVariable:to know in which column The Consecutive Value will be start
                 end
                 for bb=1:B
                     if RandomMatriceB (a,bb,ii)~=0
                        ZerosCoordinate(a,bb,ii)=StartProcess(a,bb,ii)-RandomMatriceB(a,bb,ii);%To know in which column in new matrice will have value zeros
                     else
                        ZerosCoordinate(a,bb,ii)=RandomMatriceB(a,bb,ii);
                     end
                 end
             end
       while size(find(ZerosCoordinate(:,:,ii)==43),1)<A, %looping untuk mendapatkan hari libur diminggu ke 43
           for a=1:A;
              if numel(find(ZerosCoordinate(a,:,ii)==43))==1, %mengharuskan adanya libur di minggu ke 43
                 continue;
              else
                 %make sure sum of element new random row in RandomMatriceB
                 %<=11
                 newRow = randi([0 2],1,B);
                 sumnewRow=sum(newRow,2);
                 while sumnewRow >11,
                       newRow = randi([0 2],1,B);
                       sumnewRow=sum(newRow,2);
                 end
                 %replace newRow to row in RandomMatriceB
                 RandomMatriceB(a,:,ii)=newRow; %proses pergantian baris yang tidak sesuai dengan konstrain
                 %random row in RandomMatriceA
                 RandomMatriceA(a,:,ii)=randperm(B); %randoming baris kromosom yang tidak sesuai dengan konstrain
                 %Try to know variabel to make NewMatrice
                 for b=1:B;
                     ConvertMatriceA(a,b,ii)=ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(a,b,ii));
                     ProcessRandomMatriceA(a,b,ii)=ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(a,b,ii))+RandomMatriceB(a,b,ii);
                     EndProcess=cumsum(ProcessRandomMatriceA,2);
                     StartProcess(a,b,ii)=EndProcess(a,b,ii)-(ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(a,b,ii))-1);
                 end
                 for b=1:B
                     %To know column and row which has value zeros
                    if RandomMatriceB(a,b,ii)~=0
                       ZerosCoordinate(a,b,ii)=StartProcess(a,b,ii)-RandomMatriceB(a,b,ii);
                    else
                       ZerosCoordinate(a,b,ii)=RandomMatriceB(a,b,ii); 
                    end
                end
             end
           end
       end
       %To make one combining matrice to replace combining matrice which
       %doesnt have total=0
       max_row= 85;
       DummyResult = zeros(A, max_row);
       for bbb= 1 : B
           for aaa= 1 : A
               su = StartProcess(aaa,bbb,ii);
               cu = ConvertMatriceA(aaa,bbb,ii);
               vu = RandomMatriceA(aaa,bbb,ii);
               DummyResult(aaa, su : su + cu - 1) = vu;
           end
       end


        indhasil= arrayfun(@(b) (DummyResult == b).*cumsum((DummyResult == b),2),nonzeros(unique(DummyResult)), 'UniformOutput', false);  %indikator pemakaian bagian

        SumOnePerColumnIndhasil=cell(1,4);
        SumOnePerColumnIndhasil{1}=sum(indhasil{1}==1);
        SumOnePerColumnIndhasil{2}=sum(indhasil{2}==1);
        SumOnePerColumnIndhasil{3}=sum(indhasil{3}==1);
        SumOnePerColumnIndhasil{4}=sum(indhasil{4}==1);

        %to know how many column that has not yet had
        %SumOnePerColumnIndhasil= 2 and 0.
        gabbh=cell(1,4);
        gabbh{1}=sum(SumOnePerColumnIndhasil{1}~=0 &SumOnePerColumnIndhasil{1}~=2);
        gabbh{2}=sum(SumOnePerColumnIndhasil{2}~=0 &SumOnePerColumnIndhasil{2}~=2);
        gabbh{3}=sum(SumOnePerColumnIndhasil{3}~=0 &SumOnePerColumnIndhasil{3}~=2);
        gabbh{4}=sum(SumOnePerColumnIndhasil{4}~=0 &SumOnePerColumnIndhasil{4}~=2);


        total(1,1,ii)=gabbh{1}+gabbh{2}+gabbh{3}+gabbh{4};
       end      
    end 
end
```

Comment: That is a *lot* of code. It would be better if you could pinpoint the exact spot where the code is slow, or at least the general area/operation.

Comment: I dont know which code that make my code is slow. or i do some mistake specially in when computer read while looping

Comment: Posting broken code (see @Mehrwolf's answer) is a great way to get a kicking here on SO.  Those of us who look at Matlab questions here on SO are (surely) forming the opinion that question by question we're writing your code for you but that you are not doing much learning from the help you are being given.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark:thanks for your suggestion mr. :) and I am sorry Mr that still cannot understand about matlab. but surely,I learn everything that you given to me Mr. But untill i cannot make faster code.

Comment: If you are really having so much trouble with Matlab I strongly suggest that you stop trying to tackle large problems until you are comfortable tackling small problems.  Keep working at it and one day you too will be answering Matlab questions here on SO but right now you seem to be in the position of a novice who won't give up arm-bands in the swimming pool.  Take a deep breath and jump in, but jump in at the shallow end first.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark:oke mr, i hope i will be a matlab master at the future. Really i have studied matlab since 2-3 month ago. so sorry, if I always SO here be busy. :), but i dont know why this code took long time when i run it.

Answer (score 6):

On my machine, the code is **really fast**, because it **immediately** aborts with an error ;-)

Some problems:

1. Line 25: There is no `randint()` function (I'm using Matlab R2011b).
2. Line 30: This `SumRandomMatriceB(:,:,ii)=sum(RandomMatriceB(:,:,C),2);` does not 
   work because
   `size(SumRandomMatriceB(:,:,ii)) == 1x12` but 
   `size(sum(RandomMatriceB(:,:,1),2)) == 8 x 1`, so there is a dimension mismatch.
3. Line 58: There is no function or matrix called `libur`.
4. Line 89: The `ProcessMatriceA` matrix has never been created.
5. Line 90: The variable `bb` is not decleared.

I went only through half of your code and already found **five critical errors**. Honestly, I'm not in the mood to fix these errors for you. However, when you have a running version of your code, I suggest to enter

```
profile viewer
```

in the command line. It will bring up the profiler. Just tell it the file name of your code
and it will bring up very nice timing diagrams and statistics. After profiling, you can ask very specifically, which portion of the code is slow and I'm happy to provide workarounds, if possible.

Comment: @Mehworlf: hemmm... i had edited it already mr. oke thanks for your information mr. i will try use profile viewer. :)

Comment: why cannot I close profiler when it is running mr?? and i also cannot stop my code. how to solve it?

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono: Let's assume that your file is called `testcode.m`. In the profiler window, enter `testcode` in the edit field next to the text 'Run this code:'. Then press on 'Start profiling'. When your program does not stop: Add an `error('Forced stop')` in line 23 of your code. If the program then completes, move the error statement to line 27 and run the program again. Then move the `error` to line 38 and so on. So you can find out, **which** part of the code does run forever.

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono: And of course: If the profiler does not finish, because your program never stops, press `CTRL + C` in the **command** window of Matlab. This will cancel your program and stop the profiler.